# What is the 10th point of the interpretation of this Doha: राम राम सब कोई कहे, दशरथ कहे ना कोय, एक बार दशरथ कहे कोटि यज्ञ फल होय?

Tags: mantras, shloka, quote

I watched a video in which Avimukteshwaranand Shankaracharya of Jyotir Math (Dehradun, Uttarakhand) corrected this doha and gave an interpretation based on the corrected version.

I saw many random videos by typing this famous incorrect version of this doha in Google and found that almost all are saying it wrong and they don't even understand the original and corrected version with meaning. I don't know why people in India are so dormant towards knowing the truth. I saw videos of many Katha Kar using incorrected versions of the doha.

Famous version (the incorrect one): "राम राम सब कोई कहे, **दशरथ** कहे ना कोय, एक बार **दशरथ** कहे कोटि यज्ञ फल होय".

Corrected version: "राम राम सब कोई कहे, **दश ऋत** कहे ना कोय, एक बार **दश ऋत** कहे कोटि यज्ञ फल होय".

That is, everyone says, "राम राम" but if they say "राम राम" keeping these 10 things in mind then only their chatting will fructify.

**NOTE**: Here, "राम राम" signifies name chatting, it can be "ॐ नमः शिवाय", or "ॐ गंग गणपतये नमो नमः", or any other name chatting.

Those 10 points to keep in mind and practice in life are as follows:

1. One should stop condemnation of all saintly beings (Gurus, Saints, Yogis, Gods, Demi-Gods, etc.)
2. One should not talk about God in front of a person who is not gentleman (One who is not सज्जन पुरुष).
3. Give up the thought that Iswara Vishnu & Iswara Shiva (Embodiment of Shiva is Mahadev) are different (They are the same but acting differently).
4. One who does not believe in Vedas and Shruti
5. One who does not believe in Shastras
6. One who does not believe in  Gurus or Updeshak (Preacher)
7. People who think that taking just the name of God will not do much i.e.अर्थवाद, they think that just taking God's name will not change their current situation because those people want something in return instantly.
8. To do "पाप", bad karmas (knowing that you are doing Paap) then take the chatting name of God so that God will correct it.
9. Don't compare chanting God's name with anything else or the Dharma of someone else.
10. `Unfortunately he explained only 9 thinking that he explained all 10`

> Can someone please help me with 10th point?